# CSS3 transform not working when code is sequential

Tags: css, css-transitions

How would you sequentially activate CSS3 transforms?
I'm trying the following:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sample = $('<div style="text-align:center;">hello</div>');
    sample.appendTo($('body'));

    sample.css('transform', 'scale(1.0)');
    sample.css('transition', 'all 1s ease-in-out');
    sample.css('transform', 'scale(2.0)');
</script>
```

It ignores the transition completely and just sets the scale.

Answer (score 0):

From Mozilla's docs:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Guide/CSS/Using_CSS_transitions

> Care should also be taken when using a transition immediately after
>   adding the element to the DOM using .appendChild() or removing its
>   display: none; property. This is seen as if the initial state had
>   never occured and the element was always in its final state. The easy
>   way to overcome this limitation is to apply a window.setTimeout() of a
>   handful of milliseconds before changing the CSS property you intend to
>   transition to.

So the solution ends up being:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var sample = $('<div style="text-align:center;">hello</div>');
    sample.appendTo($('body'));

    sample.css('transform', 'scale(1.0)');
    sample.css('-moz-transition', 'all 1s ease-in-out');

    setTimeout(function () {
        sample.css('transform', 'scale(2.0)');
    }, 10);
</script>
```